# CSS - Select ids that contains a pattern

Tags: jquery, css

I need to get cretive with css and I'm afraid my knowledge has hit a wall. I need to select all ids that contain map-popup.

EG:

```
#map-popup-1
#map-popup-2
#map-popup-3
#map-popup-4
```

but also exclude the one I am working with using jquery

```
$('#geo-result-block').click(function(){
   //this line I need to say all ids with map-popup have a z-index of 100 except map-popup-5
   $('#map-popup-5').css('z-index', '200').fadeIn(500);
});
```

UPDATE:

The "not" method was unnecessary

This is my final code which seems to work fine:

```
$('#geo-result-block').click(function(){
        var $mp = $('[id^="map-popup"]');
        $($mp).css('z-index', '100');
        $('#map-popup-5').css('z-index', '200').fadeIn(500);
    });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `attribute starts with` selector:

```
var $mp = $('[id^="map-popup"]');
```

And for excluding elements, you can use `not` method:

```
$mp.not('#map-popup-5');
```